# javascript element.click() issue Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser

On click of 'subButton2' button, 'uploadBtn'(display:none;) is clicked.

According to this it should be cross browser:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_html_click

Here is my code that works in chrome, opera and firefox but fails in safari:

```
var page = window.location.toString();
if(page.indexOf('register') !== -1){
    var subButton2 = document.getElementById("subButton2");
    subButton2.onclick = function () {
        var uploadBtn = document.getElementById("fileBtnHide");
        //THIS FAILS IN SAFARI IF uploadBtn style= display:none;
        uploadBtn.click();
    };
 };
```

***Only javascript, no jquery solutions, please

It's running on:
http://monkey-me.herokuapp.com/register

The Photo button is the one that triggers the second button.

Comment: I believe it should be `window.location.href` or am I missing something?

Comment: No I have tested that both location is detected and subButton2 is pressed

Comment: If i remove 'display:none;' which affects the 'uploadBtn' then the press of subButton2 clicks uploadBtn....but the howl point to begin with was to hide the file upload button cause style is hard to apply to it!!!???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting it to display none (which safari might interpret as disabled) hide it with some other css properties.

```
#fileBtnHide {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I did not wanna use visibility:hidden; because of the gap but of course u can just put height and width to 0...so silly. Thanks brother, it worked fine